# Cocoa pods issue after modify Pods file

Tags: cocoapods

when I change Pods file I get this error after command pod install

```
/Users/mac/Documents/Projects/Test/Podfile:1: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting '('
platform :ios, ‘7.0’
                     ^. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.
```

So how I can update it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Replace the 'curly quotes' around the platform with single quotes:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that's the issue and you have installed cocoapods via gem:

```
gem update --system
```

updates gem itself

```
gem update cocoapods
```

updates cocoapods.

Answer (score 1):

Just had and then resolved this issue. Using TextEdit on Mac the quotes are 'smart quotes' (as the other answers note.). However, I resolved this issue not by just turning off smart quotes, but by changing the document type from Rich Text to Plaintext, then deleting the original file and rebuilding it from scratch.

$ pod install worked fine for me after that.

Comment: Yes seems text edit replace quotes automatically, good suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Always open podfile in xcode, Otherwise quotes will changed.

platform :ios, '7.0'

Comment: yea agree or use any other text edit tools that don't modify your symbols =)

Answer (score 0):

After many variations, i simply tried:

```
platform :ios, "7.1"
```

and my particular cocoapods troubles went away.

Answer (score 0):

Smart quotes options is by default on in TextEditor.
Open podfile in vi and just place single quote before and after pod spec, it would work.